# Output format incorrect

Tags: python

I am trying to take a text file with dates and reformat them. Ex: '1/31/2017' becomes '2017-1-31T:00:00:00Z'

Code:

```
with open('dateformat.txt', 'r') as f, open('output2.txt','w') as myfile:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        a,b,c = line.split("/")

        if len(a) < 2:
            a = "0" + a

        if len(b) <2:
            b = "0" + b

        print(str(c)+"-"+str(a)+"-"+str(b)+"T:00:00:Z")

        myfile.write(str(c)+"-"+str(a)+"-"+str(b)+"T:00:00:Z"+'\n')
```

The program runs, but the output has a weird formatting where the year is on a row by itself and there is a new line after the year. I am trying to make it on one line. Also, the code will run fine for a few, but then it spits out an error Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

OUTPUT Format

2016

-07-07T:00:00:Z

2017

-02-23T:00:00:Z

Error Message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pubdateformat2.py", line 7, in 
    a,b,c = line.split("/")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Parsing date strings isn't a good practice. It may fail depending upon locale and/or implementation details. Use numerous date format features instead, or use data decomposition functions and then combine the elements as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)** module to reformat to your required datetime format.

**Demo:**

```
import datetime

s = '1/31/2017'
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT:%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

**Output:**

```
2017-01-31T:00:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the year variable(c) was at the end of the line on the file, when you use `split()`   to split each line  the newline character just sticks with it. Use strip to remove it.
Instead of `str(c)` use `str(c).strip()`